# Animation Nodes's vector distance : can't make it work like in the official example

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes

I was reading [this AN documentation page about Vector Distance](http://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/vector/vector_distance.html).

I don't know if it is still up-to-date, but I recreate the same setup and I can't make it work the same way:

it seems that the position of my empty is ignored.

Can anyone help ?

[image]

[Here's my blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zv3fhgkgpiqk8hc/gridTest.blend?dl=0).

Comment: please also provide a screenshot of your node setup. Maybe this question can be answered with looking at the actual .blend file (I can't open it right now because I'm not at my pc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Empty in your blend file isn't in the boxes' plane but 8.4 BU above it. With the current node setup the boxes will only be affected when the Empty is closer to 1 BU to the boxes' center, which perhaps didn't happen if you only moved the Empty in top view.

[image: Z location of Empty]

If the Empty is moved within the Z=0 plane the boxes will scale correctly.

You might also want to consider adding a *Math/Multiply* node after the *Vector Distance* node, or use smaller boxes, if you want to affect more than one box at a time. With the current size of your boxes only one of them will be closer than 1 BU to the Empty.

Comment: "the boxes will only be affected when the Empty is closer to 1 BU to the boxes' center" > how do you know that ?

Comment: @gordie Strictly speaking, “affected” probably is the wrong word. But the *Vector Distance* node is connected to a *Clamp* node. Any distance greater than 1 BU will be clamped to the value 1 which will result in a scaling factor of 1, i.e. you won't see any change. If you keep the current dimensions of the boxes you can add a *Math/Multiply* node to scale the distance, e.g. by 0.05. Then the boxes will start to shrink as soon as the Empty moves closer than 20 BU to the boxes' centers.